# Insert empty option field inside java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am using javascript to replace `<select></select>` inside code after a certain change. What I would like to do is to insert an empty `<option></option>` field inside this select before the DB results start populating. Here is a segment of my java script code:

```
$('#selectcity').on('change', function (){
    $.getJSON('select_sector_backend.php', {customerId: $(this).val()}, function(data){
        var options = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['sectorname'] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#selectsector').html(options);
```

so results now is:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

so I would like to be able to make it:

```
<option value="">ALL</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
```

Any help will be very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the below changes

```
$('#selectcity').on('change', function (){
    $.getJSON('select_sector_backend.php', {customerId: $(this).val()},        function(data){
    var options = '<option value="">ALL</option>';
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['sectorname'] + '</option>';
    }
    $('#selectsector').html(options);
```

Comment: This is working however it is inserting only the text ALL without the code.

Comment: The tag name is `option`, not `options`.

Comment: Yes it was. Made the necessary changes. Thanks @PeterKA

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var options = '';
```

To:

```
var options = '<option value="">ALL</option>';
```